# Using sort first in X field and then in Y field without losing the X field order UNIX

Tags: sorting, unix, syntax

I'm doing a sort, I have 6 fields and I want to sort them by number in the field 2, and then
I want to sort field 6 without losing the condition established by the field 2 sorting.

I have tried

```
$sort -k6,6 -k2,2
$sort -k2,2 -k6,6
$sort -k6,2
```

I just don't understand the syntaxis and I don't know if it's even possible. I don't understand --help very well

sample

```
0000369254 0000172915 13 36167143 36246872 79729
0000369271 0000172915 13 35516456 36246873 730417
0000369411 0000133119 13 34392186 34411633 19447
0000381122 0000183597 22 20008595 20053449 44854
0000382291 0000133119 13 34392206 34409592 17386
0000382706 0000183597 22 20008612 20053385 44773
0000383295 0000172915 13 35516456 36246872 730416
0000384827 0000183597 22 20008662 20052887 44225
0000385662 0000183597 22 20004537 20052881 48344
0000387931 0000183597 22 20008592 20049179 40587
```

Thanks guys

Comment: Providing sample input might help (you).

Comment: You're already doing it right: `sort -k2,2 -k6,6`, is that not getting you what you expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this command to sort first sorting lines by column 2 (primary field) and then by column 6 (secondary field). This will keep intact the sorting by column 2.

```
$sort -k2,2 -k6,6 inputfile
```

The output of this command will be ad follows.

```
0000382291 0000133119 13 34392206 34409592 17386
0000369411 0000133119 13 34392186 34411633 19447
0000383295 0000172915 13 35516456 36246872 730416
0000369271 0000172915 13 35516456 36246873 730417
0000369254 0000172915 13 36167143 36246872 79729
0000387931 0000183597 22 20008592 20049179 40587
0000384827 0000183597 22 20008662 20052887 44225
0000382706 0000183597 22 20008612 20053385 44773
0000381122 0000183597 22 20008595 20053449 44854
0000385662 0000183597 22 20004537 20052881 48344
```

Hope you need the same output.

Comment: OK, maybe I omitted something important, I have it like this
`awk '{$6 = $5 - $4}1' inputfile | sort -k6,6 -k2,2  > outputfile`
Straight from the stdout.  
Note: I just tested it, it didn't worked, my file is much bigger so I just put a fragment here

Comment: If you feel this post helped you do vote up and mark answer as correct. Thanks @Tamalero

Comment: @Tamalero - is your this command working or not? I believe it should work. Try using "sort -k2,2n -k6,6n inputfile"

Comment: Not working, even with the n. It shows the result as it was just sorted by the 6th field

Comment: Can you try the same commands without pipeline. Try running both commands one after other. May be this works.

Comment: Yup, I did the awk in one line and store it in a temporaly file, then I did the sort... still the same

Comment: According to me as awk processes a file line by line, the whole is not processed by awk. Only some part of file is written on pipe by awk and then sort start reading that content from pipe and thus only framents of your file are been sorted as the entire file is huge. This is because of parallel processing of the pipe you used in the command

Comment: @Tamalero- So you are not getting the output as I got. I feel this output is sorted correctly

Comment: Yeah it worked, I just needed to remove the n of the field 2 because it has a string

Comment: Thank you so much, i know that the rules down there says that no thank you messages... but... sorry

Comment: @Tamalero - You are welcome. Pls vote up the comments which were useful to you.